# easy way to link libraries with gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

Lets say this is my program :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double a = sqrt(20);
    return 0;
}
```

When we use a math function we have to include the header "math.h" file. 
But when it comes to compiling with `gcc`, we have also have to specify the shared libraries that our program uses (in this case it is the math library). To do that we use the option `-lm`.

The option to add to use a shared library is not always clear (I know that it starts with `-l` which means lib, but I don't have any easy idea to get the letters which gets after the `-l`, except searching on google).

My question is : Is there a simple way that I can use to get the right option to use with gcc using the header that I have included ??

Comment: It is the practice to name a static library `libXXX.a`.  When you link it, the `lib` and `.a` parts are expected so you'd just use `-lXXX` as the option.

Comment: I know that bro. I am looking for an easy way to find out the XXX.

Comment: Perhaps the `man` page. Not aware of any easy way.

Comment: Basically, no.  Some (`-lm`, `-lc` where it's required) are conventional, but not standardized.  Others, you just need to consult the appropriate docs.

Comment: You could `find / -name "lib*.{a,so*}"` to find all library you can link to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What docs exactly do I need to consult ??!! That's what I am looking for. The ideal is finding a doc that links each include file with its library.

Comment: @Sidahmed for the standard functions, man pages are sufficient, for sqrt, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/sqrt, it explicitly states that Link with -lm.

Comment: The docs for the function(s) you are calling, of course, either specifically, or in the form of the general docs for the library from which they come.  And yes, if you're call ing a function that is not from the standard library then you ordinarily do know from which library it comes, even if you don't know the corresponding library file name.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way that I can use to get the right option to use with gcc using the header that I have included ??

Yes: read the man page, or other documentation that came with the library.

Comment: do I just use the `man` command, or there is some specific documentation that i have to read ??